# How does the Destiny Knot work when breeding in Pokemon 6th Generation?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Does the Destiny Knot *guarantee* that 5 IVs, ramdonly selected from the parents, will be passed down to the egg?

I have both parents with 4 maxed IVs.  One has HP, Atk, Def and SpDef; the other one has Atk, Def, SpDef and Speed. One of them is holding the Destiny Knot, but I'm still getting Pokemon with "decent potential overall" and only 2 or 3 maxed IVs.

How is this possible?

Comment: We're not an outlet for your rage. Capslock and swearing doesn't help you, and just clutters up your actual *question*.

Answer (score 3):

Building On @Batophobia's answer, let's look at the probabilities that occur when 5 stats *are* transferred.
[image: IV Distribution]
Getting either 2 or 3 Perfect IVs on the child will occur in roughly 56.9% of all eggs (where the Destiny Knot transferred 5 stats). If the IV checker is reporting 'decent' potential, then it would seem likely that whatever stats the two parents have that aren't 31 are quite low.

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/In-battle_effect_item#Other_items) it is not a guarantee.

> Secondary effect:
>   If held by a Pokémon in Day Care, there is a **high chance** that five of the parents' IVs will be the same on the child.

Comment: thanks. the breeding guides i've found doesn't mention anything about chances, so i thought it was for sure. also thanks for the link for bulbapedia, didn't knew something like that existed.

Comment: @Daniel Happy to help out.  Next time just try to filter out the rage before you ask :)

Comment: The wiki no longer says anything about a "high chance". I think what happens is the IVs chosen overlap, e.g if it selects Atk IV on both parents of OP's case, it appears as one IV passed on but actually both did (what Wakerra said).

Answer (score 2):

Destiny Knot means five IVs are guaranteed to pass down from between the parents, however, which IVs is totally random, and sometimes those IVs can overlap.  In other words, say stats HP, Defense and Speed pass from parent 1, and Defense and Sp Attack pass from Parent 2.  Defense has already passed from Parent 1, so, Parent 2's Defense replaces that of Parent 1.  If Parent one had a Defense stat of 31, and Parent 2 had a defense of 10, child gets the 10 Defense

Comment: I think you're right about the overlapped IV passing, so if both parents had perfect defense and both were selected, it only appears as one IV that passed on.